# im trying make a insert into with select and value

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to make a INSERT INTO with a SELECT and values, but no works.

TABLE SOURCE:

```
CREATE TABLE "MICV_PRE"."TS$SEQUENCES"
  (
    "ID_NODE"     NUMBER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "ID_TASK"     NUMBER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "ID_DOCUMENT" NUMBER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "ID_WORD"     NUMBER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "ID_TEAM"     NUMBER DEFAULT '1' NOT NULL ENABLE)
```

TABLE TO MODIFY:

```
  CREATE TABLE TS$SEQUENCES_NEW(
     "ID_CODE" VARCHAR(255 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE,
     "CODE_SUBSEQUENCE" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE,
     "VALUE"  NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE
  );
```

table source:

```
id_task | id_node | id_word 
  10    |    20   | 30
```

table to modify:

```
 id_code  | code_subsequence | value 
"id_task" | "empty"          | 10 
"id_node" | "empty"          | 20 
"id_word" | "empty"          | 30
```

Comment: whats your sql code you have tried?

Comment: INSERT INTO TS$SEQUENCES_NEW SELECT TS$SEQUENCES.ID_TASK AS "VALUE", 'ID_TASK' AS "ID_CODE", 'VACIO' AS "CODE_SUBSEQUENCE" FROM TS$SEQUENCES;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the SQL you tried is this:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO TS$SEQUENCES_NEW
  2  SELECT TS$SEQUENCES.ID_TASK AS "VALUE", 'ID_TASK' AS "ID_CODE", 'VACIO' AS "CODE_SUBSEQUENCE"
  3  FROM TS$SEQUENCES
  4  /
                                                                *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01722: invalid number


SQL>
```

This fails because the datatypes in the projection of the query don't match the order of the columns in the table.  So either change the SELECT statement or define the order in the INSERT clause:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO TS$SEQUENCES_NEW  ("VALUE", "ID_CODE","CODE_SUBSEQUENCE" )
  2  SELECT TS$SEQUENCES.ID_TASK AS "VALUE", 'ID_TASK' AS "ID_CODE", 'VACIO' AS "CODE_SUBSEQUENCE"
  3  FROM TS$SEQUENCES
  4  /

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO TS$SEQUENCES_NEW (VALUE, ID_CODE, CODE_SUBSEQUENCE)
SELECT TS$SEQUENCES.ID_TASK AS "VALUE", 'ID_TASK' AS "ID_CODE", 'VACIO' AS "CODE_SUBSEQUENCE" 
FROM TS$SEQUENCES;
```

Comment: Did it really take me eight minutes to work up the example code?  Doesn't time fly when you're having fun!

Comment: Thanks,i forgot the parameters to replace.